# How I can add former official address in manuscript?

Tags: publications, authorship

I have written a manuscript in which I have added my present university address. If I also want to add official address of my previous university, can I do that ? If yes, should I place my former official address below my present address or former address would be more suitable as footnote ?

Comment: Consult the journal style guide. As noted by @PeterJansson below, the listed affiliation should be the one where the (majority of the) work was done.

Answer (score 1):

The address is  primarily a matter of knowing where you may reside. From this perspective the former address is of less value. However, since universities use publications for their evaluation of performance adding the former address can eb a way to "thank" your old institute. This is particularly true if you did the work there. So, the suggestion would be to list the addresses with your current first. You could consider doing it the other way around if all the work has been done at the former instittute and they deserve the credit more than your new. Your new address should nevertheless be present for reasons of contact.